# Is there a possibility to group column header in kendo Grid with angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to build my header component as nested groups in kendo Angular 2 like in the image below. Can someone please guide me how to accomplish this ?

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow community . It is recommended to post a sample code with each question . please provide some sample code that show you have put some time and research ?